# Customize css for input/output chunks in xaringan

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, xaringan

I use xaringan to make presentations and would like to customize the CSS for the input and output R chunks.

Initially, I thought I could use the `class.source` and `class.output` arguments from `knitr` to set the CSS classes.

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(class.source = "foobar", 
                      class.output = "bg-warning")
```

However, those global actions don't seem to play nicely with xaringen. The following minimal example

````
---
title: Change the chunk style
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader
---


```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(class.source = "foobar", 
                      class.output = "bg-warning")
```

```{r}
mtcars[1:5, "mpg"]
```
````

produces the following rendering

[image]

If the output is set to `htlm_document` then everything play nicely, but that doesn't fix it for the xaringan presentation.

Comment: If you are trying to change the appearance of your code chunks then maybe  [this](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/242) will help!  [This](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rmarkdown-html-xaringan-r-code-chunck-titles/118653) may also help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These chunk options won't work for **xaringan** because **xaringan** doesn't use Pandoc's Markdown syntax but remark.js's. That is, they generate ```` ```{.r .class} ````, which only works for Pandoc's Markdown. I don't have time to support them in **xaringan**, but if you want to contribute a pull request on Github, here is the place to start: https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/blob/2ad2a6d/R/render.R#L195-L204 Basiscally, you wrap the source/output character strings inside `.class[]`, which is remark.js's syntax for adding classes to elements.

Without a patch, you can only apply a class name to the whole output, and style the code blocks inside the class, e.g.,

````
---
title: Change the chunk style
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
/* R code */
.foobar code.r {
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* code without language names */
.foobar code[class="remark-code"] {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

.foobar[
```{r}
mtcars[1:5, "mpg"]
```
]
````

Comment: I'll ponder on a PR. Want me raise this as an issue for discussions before implementation on the github page?

Comment: No need for an issue. You can start a PR directly if you can figure out the implementation. Thanks!